# Wordpress CSS rule doesn't apply outside admin login

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, wordpress-theming

I am having a strange problem in my wordpress website. I have installed magnium theme, and on my front page, i have a caroussel of pictures. So far so good. There is some text displayed on the pictures, and it has the `font-family : "Open-sans";` property.

When i am logged in as an admin, no problem, the CSS is properly executed. But the problem comes when I am logged out: the same page renders with default browser fonts on chrome and firefox on my computer. However this does not happen on my android chrome. I checked with the chrome dev tools, the ONLY difference i can find in CSS is the last line of compiled CSS:

- OST derived font - 17 glyphs (in admin logged in session)
- Liberation Serif - 14 glyphs (in incognito mode or logged out)

I just don't understand, any basic clues for debugging ? Is there any CSS debugger that could give me more details than the - already detailed - chrome dev tools ?

Unfortunately I cannot give the url as the website is not public yet and my client had it protected.

Comment: Check if there is class like `.loggedin` `.loggedout` added to your body or another div

Answer (score 0):

Try This
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

this is google font you can add a link in your header.php

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Or Import style with in your Style.css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600);
```

and call the Font family to your Selector ex:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```